# storing logger information asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i am building site where there are three types of user. Admin,Merchant and Assitant User. 
Where to store information so that my application will know which user has logged on( whether it is admin or assitant user or merchant)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at ASP.NET [Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) and [Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
        string path = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-mm-yy") + ".txt";
        if (!File.Exists(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)))
        {
            File.Create(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)).Close();
        }
        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)))
        {
            w.WriteLine("\r\nLog Entry : ");
            w.WriteLine("Membership.GetUser().UserName);
            w.Flush();
            w.Close();
        }
```